# drupal 7 : Undefined index: text_processing in text_content_migrate_instance_alter()

Tags: php, module, drupal-7, migration, cck

This issue is on the migration of Drupal 6 CCK fields to Drupal 7 fields.

Here is Error that repeat many time

> Notice: Undefined index: text_processing in
>   text_content_migrate_instance_alter() (line 113 of
>   E:\wamp\www\travel-local\sites\all\modules\cck\modules\content_migrate\modules\content_migrate.text.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: min in
>   number_content_migrate_instance_alter() (line 162 of
>   E:\wamp\www\travel-local\sites\all\modules\cck\modules\content_migrate\modules\content_migrate.number.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: max in
>   number_content_migrate_instance_alter() (line 163 of
>   E:\wamp\www\travel-local\sites\all\modules\cck\modules\content_migrate\modules\content_migrate.number.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: prefix in
>   number_content_migrate_instance_alter() (line 164 of
>   E:\wamp\www\travel-local\sites\all\modules\cck\modules\content_migrate\modules\content_migrate.number.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: suffix in
>   number_content_migrate_instance_alter() (line 165 of
>   E:\wamp\www\travel-local\sites\all\modules\cck\modules\content_migrate\modules\content_migrate.number.inc)

Please reply

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to "Date Migration Example" modules. Before migration we should uninstall this modules and related content.